# Outbox pattern with Spring Integration

Tags: java, microservices, spring-integration, outbox-pattern

We want to implement an Outbox pattern by using spring integration.
Starting from [this example](https://github.com/artembilan/microservices-patterns-spring-integration/blob/main/outbox/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/microservices/outbox/OutboxApplication.java), we came up with this simpeler solution:

```
protected IntegrationFlowDefinition<?> buildFlow() {
    return from("domain.event.sender")
            .channel(c -> c.queue(this.jdbcMessageStore, "outbox"))
            .handle(
                    this.messagePublisherHandler,
                    c -> c.poller(poller -> poller.fixedDelay(1000).transactional()));
}
```

This solution will take a message from "domain.event.sender", store it in the database (in case of an error) and then POLL this db to send a message to a MessageBus (via
messagePublisherHandler).

We want to have a solution that will ALSO process this message immediately after transaction synchronisation, without that we have to wait for the poller to finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a stupid answer. I just needed to change the `fixedDelay` to `0`:

```
protected IntegrationFlowDefinition<?> buildFlow() {
    return from("domain.event.sender")
            .channel(c -> c.queue(this.jdbcMessageStore, "outbox"))
            .handle(
                    this.messagePublisherHandler,
                    c -> c.poller(poller -> poller.fixedDelay(0).transactional()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be great if you show how you process a business data before sending it into this `domain.event.sender` channel for storing into so-called outbox table.

However it is just pretty simple to make this `domain.event.sender` as a `PublishSubscribeChannel` and have another subscriber which would do the logic you are asking. If you don't configure this channel for a `TaskExecutor`, both subscribers will process the same message sequentially and withing the same business transaction.

See more info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/channel/implementations.html#channel-implementations-publishsubscribechannel